# Append new row in excel file via java apache POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I have an existing xlsx file, on row 1 I have my headlines, what I need to is add new row at 2 and of course shift everything else down, and then add my data to this row. Can you please help me with this?

```
static void Append() throws EncryptedDocumentException, InvalidFormatException, IOException
{
    InputStream inp = new FileInputStream("C:/workbook.xlsx");

    Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(inp);
    Sheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);

    Row row = sheet.createRow((short) 2);
    sheet.shiftRows(1, sheet.getLastRowNum()+1, 1, true,true);
    row.createCell(0).setCellValue("A");
    row.createCell(1).setCellValue("B");
    row.createCell(2).setCellValue("This is a string");
    row.createCell(3).setCellValue(true);

    // Write the output to a file
    FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("C:/workbook.xlsx");
    wb.write(fileOut);
    fileOut.close();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed the method `shiftRows` is a good candidate for this need, you simply need to better set the parameters, like this:

```
...
// Shift of one row all the rows starting from the 3th row
sheet.shiftRows(2, sheet.getLastRowNum(), 1, true, true);
// Create my new 3th row
Row row = sheet.createRow(2);
...
```

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: firstMovedIndex, lastMovedIndex out of order
 at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaShifter.<init>(FormulaShifter.java:81)
 at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaShifter.createForRowShift(FormulaShifter.java:126)
 at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet.shiftRows(XSSFSheet.java:2970)
 at MainClass.Append(MainClass.java:67)
 at MainClass.main(MainClass.java:21)

Comment: this works with a simple  xlsx file, maybe you should provide more info about your file

Comment: you should also mention clearly in your question, the problem met

Comment: sheet.shiftRows(1, sheet.getLastRowNum(), 1, true,true);
Row row = sheet.createRow(1);